# What is the difference between Application vs App Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, facebook

I'm implementing Facebook SDK, it tells me to replace in AppDelegate.m with

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(nonnull NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options
{
```

But i see i already have the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
```

which looks the exact same except for the application vs app. What is the difference? Can I safely change "app" to "application"?

I will accept a yes or no answer, but I would also appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword labels are part of the selector (`application:openURL:Options:`), but the parameter names (to the right of the colon) are not. They're just the names internal to the method's implementation.